# only hot water is wanted?

Tags: heating

I have a switch near my  boiler (apt) for turning on my heating,
Above that I have a standered switch for heating water only.
This system was installed 10 years ago, everything was working, until
yesterday my wife turned on switch for hot water only but rads are now heating up.
Hope someone can help

Comment: Could you try rephrasing this with more detail about the problem?

Comment: Please add more details. Equipment makes and models, for one. Any changes in the recent past (not just yesterday)?

Answer (score 1):

If your heating system is anything vaguely like a Honeywell S-plan, It is possible that you have a zone valve stuck open.

[image]

I would check the zone valve. Older ones had a small lever whose position indicates if they are closed or open.

If necessary, you can replace the motorized part without undoing the plumbing joints.

[image]